# Jquery animate on a class

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors

Hey guys I am pretty new to JQuery and I have a question about animating on a child of a certain class.

I have the following:

```
    <div class="block"><img src="a.jpg" class="top"><img src="b.jpg"></div>
    <div class="block"><img src="c.jpg" class="top"><img src="d.jpg"></div>
```

I am calling the div with (this) and I would like to select the image with class 'top' to animate.

I have tried

```
$(this, 'img.top').animate({
            opacity:0
        },400);
    })
```

But it doesn't work.
Does anyone know the correct syntax to perform this selection? Thanks

Comment: Sorry I was not clear in my question. this is the div thats being moused over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `$('img.top', this)`; the `context` parameter is the second one.

It's equivalent to `$(this).find('img.top')`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. I need to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer. Just out of curiosity why is it written in that order when `$(parent child)` seems to be the opposite?

Comment: @Luke: Because the second parameter is optional.  You're right, though; it is counter-intuitive.

Comment: =/ how do I know which one to use?

Comment: @Luke: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I had initially assumed that (this) was the parent of img. Why couldn't I find it with the parent child selector?

Comment: @Luke: What were you writing?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img.top').hover(function(){$(this).animate({
            opacity:0
        },400);});
```

try that ^^^^^^^  
 :-)

also make sure this runs when the dom is there or wrap it in:

`$(function(){/*jquery stuff*/});`

Comment: Thanks for looking at my answer=). I have several images with class 'top' each in separate divs. I would only like to animate the image when the div is moused over.

Comment: `$(function(){/*jquery stuff*/});` :P

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure you are animating on the image `class="top"` inside the div `class="block"` you could do this:

```
$('.block').children('img.top').animate({opacity:0},400);
```

Obviously if you are inside a function operating on the div with the class block, you can change to:

```
$(this).children('.top').animate({opacity:0},400);
```

See a [**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Scoobler/QZYWM/3/) *Hovering over the div will use $(this) to do the animation...*